# How to change frame like using CGAffineTransform?

Tags: swift, uikit

I have `WebView`, which I want to change his size.
[image]
I use CGAffineTransform looks like -

```
let transform: CGAffineTransform = .init(scaleX: 0.2, y: 0.2)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    webView.transform = transform
}
```

Then I get result:
[image]

When I use `webView.frame = CGRect(...)`, I got result:
[image]

How to get result like CGAffineTransform, when I use frame?